# Login on facebook sdk without callback

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I would like to know if it's possible to login on Facebook api without a callback URL.
What I want to do is really "simple":
- Login on Facebook.
- Post or Delete on the wall.
- Logout of Facebook.

This is my code for login and post:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                            'app_id' => 'xxxx',
                            'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
                            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
                        ]);

                        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
                        $permissions = ['publish_actions'];
                        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(null, $permissions);
                        echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
                        try {
                            $accessToken = 'xxxx';
                            //$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
                            //echo '<a href="' . (string)$accessToken . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
                            $linkData = [
                                'link' => 'http://www.desarrollolibre.net/blog/tema/50/html/uso-basico-del-canvas',
                                'message' => $model->value,
                            ];
                            $response = $fb->post('/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
                            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

The problem here is that I have to specify the access token getting directly from developers app, because $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken() returns nothing to me.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "auto-login", you have to implement a proper login process. If you want to automate things (and you really should not autopost, because that is not allowed), you need to store a User Access Token somewhere and use it later. You may want to use an **Extended User Token** for this, because the default one is only valid for 2 hours. The Extended User Token is valid for 60 days.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/